# Node Fetch cannot get header value from headers object

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, node-fetch

I have some code using the `node-fetch` API to make an HTTP request. The code is the following:

```js
fetch('/home.html', {
    body,
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    withCredentials: true,
    //validateStatus: () => true,
    redirect: 'manual'
  })
    .then(resp => {console.log(resp.headers)
```

The bellow code when run prints an object of the HTTP response headers as follows:

```
{
  connection: 'close',
  'content-language': 'en-US',
  date: 'Sat, 03 Sep 2022 10:17:04 GMT',
  location: 'https://ps.asmadrid.org/public/home.html',
  server: 'PowerSchool SIS',
  'set-cookie': 'JSESSIONID=B2888D2BB22737AE7CF515048793DFB4; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN'
}
```

This is correct. But then if I change the `console.log` statement at the end to log the `set-cookie` header, it logs `undefined`:

```js
// ...
    .then(resp => {console.log(resp.headers['set-cookie'])
```

As far as I'm aware, the `node-fetch` headers object is a normal object with nothing special, so why isn't this working? Why can't I get an individual header value?

Comment: The server may not be setting the cookie with every request. I suggest logging the entire headers object along with the 'set-cookie' field to confirm this isn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, it's not a *normal* object, it's actually a [class](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/bcfb71c7d10da252280d13818daab6925e12c368/src/headers.js)

so you need to use `headers.get` method:

```
.then(resp => {console.log(resp.headers.get('set-cookie'))
```

see [Accessing Headers and other Metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#accessing-headers-and-other-metadata)

or in your case, you can use `headers.raw` method to get an array of valuse for this specific header:

```
.then(resp => {console.log(resp.headers.raw()['set-cookie'])
```

as described here: [Extract Set-Cookie Header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#extract-set-cookie-header)